# Tachometer for BLDC motors

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, tachometer

Is there any DIY or electronic display kit available that can sense the electrical pulses on the phase wires of a sensorless BLDC motor to calculate the RPM?

Comment: It's already doing that sensing in order to drive the motor; without it, your motor controller would quickly turn into a smoke generator most likely.

Comment: I meant if we can read that measurement of rpm on display units.

Answer (score 1):

Well this sounds like a classical application for a microcontroller that interfaces a display, and has an analog input that you can use on the AC coupled supply lines.

In short, microcontrollers are kind of the Application-Specific IC (ASIC) for exactly these kinds of control/monitoring problems. And they're available, so:

> Is there any DIY or electronic display kit

Yes! Buy a microcontroller eval board with a display.

You'll need to program it to calculate what you want to show; there's little a priori knowledge on the number of poles your motor has and what plausible speeds are.

With a bit of signal preconditioning (mostly: AC coupling, amplification, prefiltering), you might also be able to just feed your signal into something with an application processor through a microphone/audio line in port, like a laptop computer or a smartphone, and do the signal processing in easy-to-develop application software running on a fully fledged operating system.